# Special Case Lemmatization ValueError while Using spacy for NLP

Tags: nlp, spacy, lemmatization

## Special Case Lemmatization ValueError while Using spacy for NLP

### Problem (What I think is happening)

While exploring special case lemmatization, I ran into a ValueError (provided below). I actually want to modify the text, changing "Friso" to "San Francisco." Does anyone see what I am doing wrong here?

### Code

```
# (using spacy v3.4)
import spacy
from spacy.symbols import *  
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")  
doc = nlp("I am flying to Frisco.")  
special_case = [ {NORM:"Frisco", ORTH:"San Francisco"} ]  
print([token.text for token in doc])
nlp.tokenizer.add_special_case("Frisco", special_case)  
print([token.lemma_ for token in nlp("I am flying to Frisco.")])
```

### Error

`ValueError: [E997] Tokenizer special cases are not allowed to modify the text. This would map 'Frisco' to 'San Francisco' given token attributes '[{67: 'Frisco', 65: 'San Francisco'}]'`

Answer (score 1):

As the error says, tokenizer special cases cannot modify the text. spaCy does not allow modifying the text of a Doc object; this is a decision made to keep data consistent and avoid many classes of problems, even if it can be inconvenient.

Comment: Do you have a workaround to suggest?

Comment: It kind of depends, but usually you can do it by sticking the replacement text in a custom attribute and then building up an output string using the custom attribute value if present instead of the token text.